# string and arrays manipulation c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Here is the code and it is working fine for a single input string

```
string[] stop_word = new string[] 
{ 
    "please", 
    "try", 
    "something", 
    "asking", 
    "-", 
    "(", ")", 
    "/", 
    ".", 
    "was", 
    "the" 
};

string str = "Please try something (by) yourself. -befor/e asking";
foreach (string word in stop_word)
{
    str = str.ToLower().Replace(word, "").Trim();
}
```

and the output is `by yourself before`
and now I want to have

```
string str[] = new string[] 
{ 
    "Please try something-by yourself. before (CAD) asking/", 
    "cover, was adopted. The accuracy (of) the- change map was" 
};
```

and also may be the number of strings is greater than 2 then how to alter this above code to display the `str` array or store in a text file or database.

Please help with acknowledgements. Thanks

Comment: what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: So you have a new string - what are you expecting to output from that?

Comment: You already have code to clean up a single string. Move that into a method and call it on all strings in your new array.

Comment: Use another loop for your string array,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for single string need to be put inside a loop for string array

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
for(int i =0; i<str.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (string word in stop_word)
    {
        str[i] = str[i].ToLower().Replace(word, "").Trim();
        str[i] = Regex.Replace(str[i], @"\s+", " ");
    }
    result.Add(str[i]);
}

foreach(string r in result)
{
    //this is to printout the result
    Console.WriteLine(r); 
}
```

You can try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wg83gM

**EDIT:**
Use regex to replace multiple spaces with one single space

Comment: @currarpickt--its fine but why is there space issue in second string i.e.cover,  adopted  accuracy of  change map

Comment: because int the second string `"cover, was adopted. The accuracy (of) the- change map was" `, `was` and `the-` is in the middle so trim will not work. you need to check if there are more than one space between words.

Comment: @currarpickt--if i want to have result with single space after removing all stop-Words then what I have to do???

Comment: see my edit and don't forget to accept the answer if that's what you need

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy to understand way to do it:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string text in str)//loops through your str array
{
   string newText =text;
   foreach (string word in stop_word) //loops through your word array
    {
       newText =  newText.ToLower().Replace(word, "").Trim();
   }
   list.Add(newText);  //store the results in a list
}
```

**Here is a working [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/prpTL5)**

Comment: Did you actually try this code? On the given inputs it returns a 22 item list.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, my mistake i updated my answer. now undo your downvote

Comment: This still doesn't work. You do need to test before posting.

Comment: @Enigmativity it works fine, check the demo, and undo the downvote

Comment: @LuthandoLoot `it works fine`, I think you meant `it works fine now`

Comment: @LuthandoLoot - It works now that you fixed the second error.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work as you expect?

```
var results =
    str
        .Select(x => stop_word.Aggregate(x, (a, y) => a.ToLower().Replace(y, "").Trim()))
        .ToArray();
```

I used this input:

```
string[] str = new string[]
{
    "Please try something-by yourself. before (CAD) asking/",
    "cover, was adopted. The accuracy (of) the- change map was"
};

string[] stop_word = new string[]
{
    "please", "try", "something", "asking", "-", "(", ")", "/", ".", "was", "the"
};
```

I got this output:

```
by yourself before cad 
cover,  adopted  accuracy of  change map
```

Comment: I don't know why I got a down-vote. My code works perfectly as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select()` for this.

```
var results = str.Select(x => {
    foreach (string word in stop_word)
    {
        x = x.ToLower().Replace(word, "").Trim();
    }
    return x;
}).ToList(); // You can use ToArray() if you wish too.

...

foreach(string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Result:

> by yourself before cad
>
> cover,  adopted  accuracy of  change map